# Outlook Addin not appearing in the COM Add-ins list

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I've developed an Add-in for outlook in Visual Studio. When I run it, it opens up outlook correctly but does not show the Add-in within the COM list of add-ins.

I assume it's something to do with the registry, but can't seem to find the problem. When running the application I can see it creates a registry within the *`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO`* path and another within *`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins`* that contains the Manifest with the correct file path to the VSTO project.

Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where did you add windows registry keys? Could you be more specific? Do you have Windows and Outlook x64 or x86 installed?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear where your windows registry keys were added.

If the installer is targeting all users on 64-bit Windows, it is recommended that it includes two registry entries, one under the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft` and one under the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft` hive. This is because it's possible for users to use either 32-bit or 64-bit versions of Office on the computer.

If the Installer is targeting the current user, it doesn't need to install to the `WOW6432Node` because the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software` path is shared. For more information, see [32-bit and 64-bit Application Data in the Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/32-bit-and-64-bit-application-data-in-the-registry).

The [Deploying a VSTO Solution Using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-a-vsto-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2022) article describes all required steps for creating MSI installers for Office COM add-ins. Also take a look at the [Registry entries for VSTO Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/registry-entries-for-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2022) article which explains where windows registry keys should be added for VSTO/COM add-ins.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question for someone facing the same issue.

Running a repair on Office fixed my issue. To my understanding it repaired some registry key mappings.